# Comparing Teachers Based on How Many Similar Courses They Teach

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT instructors.name AS name,
substring(sections.course,1,4) AS courseCode
FROM instructors
JOIN teaches ON instructors.id = teaches.instructor_id
JOIN schedules ON teaches.schedule_id = schedules.id
JOIN sections ON schedules.section_id = sections.id
```

[This is the output of said code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiiUc.png)

What I need to do, is compare two names and see how many courseCodes they have in common. (Example: asifa amir and stephen cheung both teach a BUSI course, therefore, we add one to a "coteaches" count.

The output needs to be:

teacher1Name, teacher2Name, numberOfCoteaches

But I can't for the life of me figure out what to do to make that output.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give every pair of instructors and the number of coursecodes they share.

```
SELECT a.name name1, b.name name2, 
    count(distinct substring(seb.course,1,4)) coteaches
FROM (instructors a 
       Join teaches ta on ta.instructor_id = a.instructor_id
       Join schedules sha on sha.id = ta.ScheduleId
       Join sections sea.id = sha.sectionId)
   join (instructors b
       Join teaches tb on tb.instructor_id = b.instructor_id
       Join schedules shb on shb.id = tb.ScheduleId
       Join sections seb on seb.id = shb.sectionId)
      on substring(seb.course,1,4) = substring(sea.course,1,4)
Group By a.name, b.name
```

To do it for only one specific pair of instructors, add a where clause that restricts the output

```
Where a.Name = [Put one name here]
  and b.name = [Put the other name here]
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed! Took 17 mins for the query, but it works! You're an absolute godsend

Comment: You're very welcome.  If you add the Where clause to restrict it to just two instructors, it will not take so long.

Answer (score 0):

This is a self-join, but it is a real pain.  Why doesn't the `teaches` table have the course itself?

```
SELECT t1.instructor_id, t2.instructor_id, count(*)
FROM teaches t1 JOIN
     schedules s1
     ON t1.schedule_id = s1.id JOIN
     sections sec1
     ON s1.section_id = sec1.id JOIN
     sections sec2
     ON sec2.course_id = sec1.course_id JOIN
     schedules s2
     ON s2.section_id = sec2.id JOIN
     teaches t2
     ON t2.schedule_id = s2.id AND
        t1.instructor_id < t2.instructor_id 
GROUP BY t1.instructor_id, t2.instructor_id;
```

This would be much easier to write and more intuitive in almost any other database -- because of the support for CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the query you already have produces the table `t` then the following query produces the results.

```
SELECT t1.name1, t2.name1), COUNT(1)
FROM t AS t1 JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.courseCode = t2.courseCode
WHERE t1.name1 != t2.name1
GROUP BY t1.name1, t2.name1
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
```

The only caveat is that it produces 2 rows for each pair of teachers because `teacher1,teacher2` and `teacher2,teacher1` are differrent tuples.

Try using the `SET` [type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) in the `SELECT` statement to avoid this.